# Classification of signals, and Wavelet Transform based denoising

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, wavelet

Stationary Wavelet Transform based denoising methods are considered the best because of their translational invariance. On the other hand, Matlab promises SWT based denoising but in the ddencmp function for denoising a signal, it is actually using Discrete Wavelet Transform when it should rather threshold the SWT co-efficients. Is there something that I am missing? I will be absolutely grateful.